# SSRS error where a passed parameter has an & in the value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a hyper link to an ssrs report that is created from a DB call. One of the parameters has an & in it and causing a failure. The parameter is LOCATION=Bridge%20&%20Load%20Room.
Is there an escape Char for the & or what do I have to do to correct for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=Replace(Fields!FIELDNAME.Value, "&","%2526")
```